# Ifstream reading error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, fstream, ifstream

I have been trying to read a bmp file with ifstream, however it works fine without debugging, when I run it in debug mode it fails. At the beginning I read 54 bytes of info, to get the height and the width of the picture, which are unfortunately -858993460 in debug mode, so the whole size of my picture overflows everytime, so I get a bad allocation error. I use VS 2013, could anyone help me out with this one ?

```
unsigned char* readBMP(char* filename)
{

int i;
char info[54];
std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
ifs.read(info, 54);

// extract image height and width from header
int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];

int size = 3 * width * height;

char* data = new char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel

ifs.read(data, size);
ifs.close();
return (unsigned char*)data;

}
```

Comment: Use `std::istream::gcount()` to verify the actual bytes read matches the expected quantity.

Comment: Sou you're sure reading `witdth` and `hight` using the correct endianess?

Comment: The decimal value -858993460 is 0xFFFF,FFFF,CCCC,CCCC.  Whether Little Endian or Big Endian, the value looks wrong.  Are you reading from the correct offset?

Comment: You should use a *packed* structure as a stencil for the bitmap format in the `info` array.  Also, use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead of `char`.  The `char` type is platform dependent and can be unsigned, signed or `char`.

Comment: I guess your file failed to open, and your read was failed. you can check  `if (ifs.is_open()) { /* good*/}` you can also check: `if(ifs.read(...)){/*good*/}`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you failed to open the file, so your read must been failed.

you can check: `if (ifs.is_open()) { /* good*/}`

you can also check: `if(ifs.read(...)){/*good*/}`

try this code:

```
unsigned char* readBMP(char* filename)
{

int i;
char info[54];
std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
if(!ifs.is_open()){ 
   std::cerr<<" failed to open file"<<std::endl;
   return NULL;
 }
if(!ifs.read(info, 54)) {
  std::cerr<<" failed to read from file"<<std::endl;
  return NULL;
} 

// extract image height and width from header
int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];

int size = 3 * width * height;

char* data = new char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel

ifs.read(data, size);
ifs.close();
return (unsigned char*)data;

}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to fail to open that file in debug mode, however as I mentioned it works fine when I run directly the executable, thus I'm still wondering what difference does debug mode make.

Comment: You can set the working directory or give a full path to the image. if you just run from visual studio it run from the project location, set the debug working directory to run from the exe location, (find it in project properties ->debug).